# How to handle asynchronous error in 'Add to App' Flutter android application

Tags: flutter, error-handling, flutter-android, flutter-add-to-app, flutter-exception

I am trying to use runZonedGuarded for the handling of asynchronous error in my [Add to App](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app) project, but its never goes under the error handling when debugging, only showing as an unhandled exception in logs.

```
Future<void> main() async {
unawaited(runZonedGuarded(() async {

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
  print('This is an error on the Flutter SDK');
  print(errorDetails.exception);
  print('-----');
  print(errorDetails.stack);
};

runApp(app);

}, (error, stackTrace) {
  print('Exception handled');
  print(error);
  print('-----');
  print(stackTrace);
}));
```

Creating the asynchronous exception on button tap as below -

```
  class DebugPage extends StatelessWidget {
     DebugPage({
      Key key,
      this.navigatorKey,
      }) : super(key: key);

     void createError() async {
      print('Creating  exception.');
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => throw Exception('async error'));
     }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text("Debug"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
       children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(title: Text('Test Network Kit....'),
         onTap: () {
          createError();
         }),
       ],
      ),
     );
   }
 }
```

I tried the same process for full flutter app and its working in that project by catching the asynchronous error correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of printing error:`print(stackTrace);`

print it :  `print(DiagnosticsStackTrace('Stack', stackTrace).getProperties());`
So that you'll not be disturbed by flutter, and can handle all error properties.

Comment: It does not matter because that line of code is not executing on error. Also this doesn't answer the question.